# Is a new StringBuffer object created when the StringBuffer goes out of capacity or it remains still the old one?

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection, stringbuffer

Is a new StringBuffer object created when the StringBuffer goes out of capacity or it remains still the old one?

```
class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer sb2 = sb;
    System.out.println(sb.capacity());
    sb.append("abcdefghijklmnop");
    System.out.println(sb.capacity());
    sb.append("q");
    System.out.println(sb.capacity());
    System.out.println(sb == sb2);
 }
}
```

**input**: deep (master *) LanguagePackageInJava $ javac Lecture7.java
deep (master *) LanguagePackageInJava $ java Test
**output**: 16
16
34
true

In the above piece of code, I have tried to create a StringBuffer object **sb** and copied its reference to another StringBuffer object **sb2** when the StringBuffer **sb** was empty. I have tried to overflow the capacity of **sb** and then tried out whether a new object has been created or not by comparing **sb2** with **sb**. But it returns true. I suppose no object has been created. But I am not pretty sure about it even after going through the documentation. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
StringBuffer sb2 = sb;
```

doesn't create a copy of the `sb` object.  It only creates another reference to the same object.  Now you have two `StringBuffer` references to the same `StringBuffer` object.

```
sb  -------> StringBuffer
          /
sb2 ------
```

If you overflow the capacity of a `StringBuffer`, it will reallocate an internal buffer for the contents.

```
sb  -------> StringBuffer ----XXXXXXX"abcdefghijklmnop"
          /                  \
sb2 ------                    ------>"abcdefghijklmnopq"
```

The internal array used as a buffer for the contents will be a new object created.  The old buffer will be garbage collected eventually.

However, the `StringBuffer` object itself is not replaced.  When you append something to a `StringBuffer`, it always returns a reference to itself.  You're ignoring it, but even if you reassigned the return value back to `sb`, it's still referring to the same object.

Also, you can replace `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder` and the rest of the above would not change.

Comment: yes I should have stored the return of the append function and then compare it with sb..I did it ...still it gives the same object

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it remains the same. First, you compare `sb` and `sb2`, and they are the same, and second, you do not do any assignment to `sb`, so it only can be the same as before.